# flutter_native_splash image is always cropped

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter_native_splash to add an image to the splash screen. However, no matter how big the image is, it is always cropped.

This is the example image, 132 * 250 pixel

[image]

The code is

```
flutter_native_splash:
  android_12:
    image: assets/logo_lockup_flutter_vertical.png
    color: "#FFFFFF"
  ios: true
  android: true
  image: assets/logo_lockup_flutter_vertical.png
  color: "#FFFFFF"
```

The splash screen is

[image]

Can I please get some help?

Thank you

> flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2283], locale en-AU)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted. To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.4)
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include these  
      components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources
```

Comment: Speaking about Android splash screens please have a look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen) . Long story short: it is not possible to set an image as a background screen, only as an icon. This is why it tries to fit your big image into the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found a workaround. I added a transparent background with bigger size to the image (I use black background for illustration)

[image]

Then it will be like this in my app. I need to tune the size of the background to find a good ratio.

[image]